# Prettier in Javascript is forcing variable Definition onto next line

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, prettier

I am using typescript, prettier and eslint and I'm trying to define a multiline string variable like so:

```
const text = 'Some really long interesting text' + 
    ' some more really really long text' +
    ' and some even more really long text';
```

However, when I run eslint with the fix option, prettier is forcing my code to look like this.

```
const text =
    'Some really long interesting text' +
    ' some more really long interesting text' +
    ' and some even more really long text';
```

I would prefer the `+` operators to be before the text but I understand that prettier won't let me do that due to it's opinion. Fine. But I don't understand the variable definition starting on the next line. I've never seen the variable definition start on the next line before.

Can anyone help me answer either of these questions:

1. Where this came from? I've never seen this standard before and how did Prettier decide to adopt it? The documentation about this is rather bleak.
2. Is there anyway I can override it?

Here's my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    extends: [
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    rules: {
        // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
        // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off'
    },
};
```

And here is my .prettierrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    semi: true,
    trailingComma: "es5",
    singleQuote: true,
    printWidth: 120,
    tabWidth: 4
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding this eslint rule [operator-linebreak](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/operator-linebreak)?

Comment: That is how prettier format your code, you cannot change that.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to change that, since prettier plugin disables all its conflicting rules with eslint.

You may want to try [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint) instead. It formats the code first via prettier and then passes to eslint.

> This formats your code via prettier, and then passes the result of that to eslint --fix. This way you can get the benefits of prettier's superior formatting capabilities, but also benefit from the configuration capabilities of eslint.

Add eslint [operator-linebreak](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/operator-linebreak) rule and `--fix` should do the work.

Rule

```js
'operator-linebreak': ['error', 'before']
```

> Where this came from? I've never seen this standard before and how did Prettier decide to adopt it? The documentation about this is rather bleak.

It is not a standard. It is a style that Prettier has adopted. Line breaks are accepted in javascript. Line breaks are ignored until

- when the next line starts with code that breaks the current one (code can spawn on multiple lines)
- when the next line starts with a }, closing the current block
- when the end of the source code file is reached
- when there is a return statement on its own line
- when there is a break statement on its own line
- when there is a throw statement on its own line
- when there is a continue statement on its own line

Source: [Javascript Automatic Semicolons](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20semicolons%20are%20optional.&text=This%20is%20all%20possible%20because,is%20called%20Automatic%20Semicolon%20Insertion)

Also see [Why Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/why-prettier.html)

Comment: Hi Sibaraj, thanks for responding. That did the trick but it doesn't answer my other question. Where did the variable definition starting on the next line ever come from? How and why did anyone in javascript ever decide that that was "prettier"?

Comment: It is from prettier. Try running same the code here https://prettier.io/playground

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Im sorry, I guess I dont understand how that answers my question. Where did anyone putting a linebreak after the = operator in a variable declaration come from? To say that's how JavaScript works doesn't seem sufficient to me because you don't see that in every variable declaration.

Comment: It is a style adopted by prettier since it is not wrong to have line breaks after operators.

Comment: @DimeZilla, you're correct about your assumption. The prettier maintainers came up with that format themselves, it's very unattractive IMHO, and doesn't make any sense. It especially doesn't make sense as a default format, even more so that it can't be optionally disabled.